# R: concatenate unknown number of strings with common character

Tags: r

The goal is to insert `<br>` in front of every sentence. For example:

```
df=(info="this text doesn't mean anything and it's only here as a demonstration. You can replace this with anything else and I want to somehow wrap this text")
```

what I want is:

```
"this text doesn't mean anything and it's only here as a demonstration." "<br>" "You can replace this with anything else and I want to somehow wrap this text"
```

here is what my best try but somehow it doesn't work:

```
paste(strsplit(as.character(df$info)[1],"[.]"),sep="<br>")
```

Comment: Do you want a vector of length 3 where the second element is "<br>" or a vector of length 1 with <br> in between the sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dots are what specify a sentence you could use `gsub`:

```
gsub('\\.', '. <br>', df)
```

Which would return:

```
[1] "this text doesn't mean anything and it's only here as a demonstration. <br> You can replace this with anything else and I want to somehow wrap this text"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your attempt doesn't work is that `strsplit` is returning a list, whereas you want to paste the first element of that list using `[[1]]`... and then collapse with `". <br>"`

```
paste(strsplit(as.character(df$info)[1],"[.] ")[[1]], collapse =". <br>")
```